# Implement a Twitter Like Feed(Data From Server) in a list view in Android

Tags: java, android, twitter

I am looking for any suggestions/ways to implement a Twitter Like Data Feed in Android (Each Item is Clickable and opens a dialog /new activity screen on a click).
The Data is fetched from server,implemented in java. IS there a common pattern/way to do this.
we have implemented the server side code, serves data in JSON format.
Any Suggestions/examples/references ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like the following example:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String RANK = "rank";
    static String COUNTRY = "country";
    static String POPULATION = "population";
    static String FLAG = "flag";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("rank", jsonobject.getString("rank"));
                    map.put("country", jsonobject.getString("country"));
                    map.put("population", jsonobject.getString("population"));
                    map.put("flag", jsonobject.getString("flag"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

**JSON:**

```
{
    "worldpopulation": [
        {
            "rank": 1,
            "country": "China",
            "population": "1,354,040,000",
            "flag": "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/china.png"
        },
        {
            "rank": 2,
            "country": "India",
            "population": "1,210,193,422",
            "flag": "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/india.png"
        },
        {
            "rank": 3,
            "country": "United States",
            "population": "315,761,000",
            "flag": "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/unitedstates.png"
        },
        {
            "rank": 4,
            "country": "Indonesia",
            "population": "237,641,326",
            "flag": "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/indonesia.png"
        },
        {
            "rank": 5,
            "country": "Brazil",
            "population": "193,946,886",
            "flag": "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/brazil.png"
        },
        {
            "rank": 6,
            "country": "Pakistan",
            "population": "182,912,000",
            "flag": "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/pakistan.png"
        },
        {
            "rank": 7,
            "country": "Nigeria",
            "population": "170,901,000",
            "flag": "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/nigeria.png"
        },
        {
            "rank": 8,
            "country": "Bangladesh",
            "population": "152,518,015",
            "flag": "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/bangladesh.png"
        },
        {
            "rank": 9,
            "country": "Russia",
            "population": "143,369,806",
            "flag": "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/russia.png"
        },
        {
            "rank": 10,
            "country": "Japan",
            "population": "127,360,000",
            "flag": "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/japan.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Look at the following link for details:**

[Android JSON Parse Images and Texts Tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/)

Comment: FYI, It's not an answer. You should include essential part of the article/link here because article/link may no longer exist in future.

Comment: Thanks @fida1989. besides this, what changes can we do to implement a Endless List with above code, such as when the user scrolls to bottom and we fetch new set of JSON Array to display. Like as it is in twitter.

Comment: For that you have to use custom listview implementation for endless listview. Check out this example: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/10/android-listview-endless-adapter.html.